# Visual Studio Build Error: The target "MainResourceGeneration" does not exist in the project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2017

Getting the following error '**The target "MainResourceGeneration" does not exist in the project**' on Any project I try to build with Visual Studio. Cannot run debugger, cannot build/rebuild solution or projects.

Backing up a bit:

- I had VS2012 and VS2017 (always used 2017) installed.
- Got an error that pointed me to the Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets file. I mistakenly edited this file thinking it was part of my project.
- Started getting the aforementioned build error on all my projects. Including simple, brand new, unaltered C# .NET framework console app.
- Also had the same error on VS2012...
- Tried VS2017 repair.
- Tried VS2017 uninstall/reinstall.
- Tried uninstall VS2017/2012, manually delete visual studio program files folders, reinstall 2017.

Still have the problem. Brand new fresh VS2017 install and not even a new console app will build.

Build output just shows this...
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2789,7): error MSB4057: The target "MainResourcesGeneration" does not exist in the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried several further steps like manually deleting Visual Studio related folders in my Users and ProgramData directories, and repairing .NET framework. None of those changes worked. Still had the same issue.

As a last resort I fully uninstalled .NET Framework (4.7.1) and grabbed the latest version (4.7.2) from https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/dotnet-framework-runtime. I no longer received the error and could then build my projects again.

I do not know or understand the root cause, but a full uninstall/reinstall of .NET framework fixed it...

Answer (score 0):

> Visual Studio Build Error: The target “MainResourceGeneration” does not exist in the project

Since this issue still occurs on a new console app, it seems that the Visual Studio installation file is corrupted. You can try to following steps to clean up the Visual Studio and reinstall it:

- See if you have this file on your machine:
  "%programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual
  Studio\Installer\resources\app\layout\InstallCleanup.exe"
- Start an admin command prompt
- Right-click on cmd.exe and select Run AsAdministrator
- If so, please launch it from an admin command prompt with a -full
  param

  InstallCleanup.exe -full
- If not, please manually delete the "%programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft
  Visual Studio\Installer” folder
- Verify that your initial install location for VS is removed.  If it
  is not, delete it manually.
- Relaunch the newly downloaded vs_enterprise.exe (or
  vs_professional.exe or vs_community.exe…)
- Allow the first step to install the installer  Once the installer
  comes up and you can see workload choices (.net desktop and the
  like), close it
- Go launch the same InstallCleanup.exe to clean up old build of VS
- Then relaunch vs_enterprise.exe and install VS

Please let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Just went through all of this as specified, but no change. Still get 'The target "MainResourceGeneration" does not exist in the project." on an empty console app.